# How to prevent the "Flash is required" popup from showing in Firefox and Chrome?

Tags: firefox, google-chrome, flash, browser, adobe

Flash is not, and will not be installed, so Firefox and Chrome (and others) nag me with the flash popup that it is not installed and is needed for certain websites.

How do I block or prevent browsers from prompting me to install the Flash plugin? I do not want to install Flash.

Answer (score 2):

You can install an extension that blocks the Flash plugin execution in Firefox.

I use NoScript, it has a lot of other functionality:

https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/noscript/

There is another simpler one called Flashblock that does just that:

https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/flashblock/

Comment: Both would solve your problem, and NoScript is a great security enhancer, especially if you don't often visit sites that use scripts (Java, Javascript, etc.)